# asp.net read from file to table

Tags: asp.net, file, html-table

I want to read a file and output the lines from it to an HTML table in my webpage..

I render the HTML table with this code:

```
        if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path))
                {

                    Response.Write("<table style=\"width:1000px;\">");
                    while (tr.Peek() != -1)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<tr><td style=\"width:50%;\">");
                        Response.Write(String.Join("</td><td style=\"width:50%\">", tr.ReadLine().Split('\t')));
                        Response.Write("</td></tr>");
                    }
                    Response.Write("</table>");

                }
            }
```

But if the data length in some lines is too long, this table column doesn't follow its length, and use "enter" to make it 2 rowa..

How do I make long length lines display on only 1 row ?

Comment: Rather than wrap to mulitple lines, do you want the text to overflow the end of the space if the length of the data is greater than the space available?

Comment: yappp, how is that ? actually i make it in table because when it read my file it didnt read "tab" it only read "space".. maybe you have any solution ?

Comment: what do you mean it didn't read tab?

Comment: "tab" on keyboard sir..

Comment: You need a couple of CSS styles.  I think this will work (but I'm not in a place to be able to try it).  Try this for the second line in your `while` block: `Response.Write(String.Join("</td><td style=\"width:50%;overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;\">", tr.ReadLine()));`  And I'm pretty sure you do NOT want the `Split()` call in there.